# prove $k^2 = k^2_g + k^2_n$

Tags: differential-geometry

How do I prove $k^2 = k^2_g + k^2_n$?

Where $k$ is the curvature ||$T'$||, $k_g$ is geodesic curvature, and $k_n$ is the normal curvature

I'm not quite sure where to start.

Maybe it has something to do with this

$T' = kN = (kN \cdot (n \times T))(n \times T) + (kN\cdot n)n = k_g(n \times T) + k_n(n)$

$k =||T'|| = \sqrt{k_g^2(n \times T)^2 + k_n^2(n)^2}$

$k^2 = k_g^2(n \times T)^2 + k_n^2(n)^2$

Then $n \times T$ and $n^2$ are 1 for some reason

Comment: You should give some context and definition

Comment: I added some context with what each $k$ meant

Comment: You should not write $n^2$. Write either $n\cdot n$ or $\|n\|^2$. Now can you finish?

Comment: Is it because n is a unit normal and $||n||^2 = 1$? I'm not sure why $(n \times T) \cdot (n \times T)$ would be 1

Comment: What do you know about $n$ and $T$, and what do you know about cross product? You need to keep basics at your fingertips.